# Fast slicing of numpy array multiple times

Tags: python, numpy, slice

I have something like a np.arange([100000]) and i need to retrieve data between two indexes multiple times. Currently i running this which is slow

```
data = np.arange([100000])
# This array usually contains thousands of slices
slices = np.array( [
       [1, 4],
       [10,20],
       [100,110],
       [1000,1220]
])

# One way i have been doing it
np.take(data, [i for iin, iout in slices for idx in range(iin, iout)])
# The other way
[data[iin:iout] for iin, iout in slices]
```

Both ways are slow. I need this to be very fast. I looking for something like this.

```
data[slices[:,0], slices[:,1]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Some timings with your `slices` and `data = np.arange(2000)`

Your `take`, corrected:

```
In [360]: timeit np.take(data, [idx for iin, iout in slices for idx in range(iin,iout)])
10000 loops, best of 3: 92.5 us per loop

In [359]: timeit data[[idx for iin, iout in slices for idx in range(iin,iout)]]
10000 loops, best of 3: 92.2 us per loop
```

Your 2nd version (corrected) - quite a bit better

```
In [361]: timeit np.concatenate([data[iin:iout] for iin,iout in slices])
100000 loops, best of 3: 15.8 us per loop
```

Using `np.r_` to concatenate slices - not much of an improvement over your 1st.

```
In [362]: timeit data[np.r_[tuple([slice(i[0],i[1]) for i in slices])]]
10000 loops, best of 3: 79 us per loop
In [363]: timeit np.r_[tuple([slice(i[0],i[1]) for i in slices])]
10000 loops, best of 3: 67.5 us per loop
```

Constructing the index takes the bulk of the time.

Of course rankings at this size might change with a much scaled up problem.

Since your slices vary in length, there isn't much hope of generating them all in a vectorized way, that is 'in parallel'.  I don't know if a `cython` implementation would speed it up much or not.

More timings from an earlier similar question
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11062055/901925