# Numpy Array: Slice several values at every step

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray, numpy-slicing

I am trying to extract several values at once from an array but I can't seem to find a way to do it in a one-liner in Numpy.

Simply put, considering an array:

```
a = numpy.arange(10)
> array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

I would like to be able to extract, say, 2 values, skip the next 2, extract the 2 following values etc. This would result in:

```
array([0, 1, 4, 5, 8, 9])
```

This is an example but I am ideally looking for a way to extract `x` values and skip `y` others.

I thought this could be done with slicing, doing something like:

```
a[:2:2]
```

but it only returns 0, which is the expected behavior.

I know I could obtain the expected result by combining several slicing operations (similarly to [Numpy Array Slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11061928/numpy-array-slicing)) but I was wondering if I was not missing some numpy feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a modulo operator:

```
x = 2 # keep
y = 2 # skip

out = a[np.arange(a.shape[0])%(x+y)<x]
```

Output: `array([0, 1, 4, 5, 8, 9])`

Output with `x = 2 ; y = 3`:

```
array([0, 1, 5, 6])
```

Comment: Nice! and if I want to keep exactly the opposite I can do 
`a[np.arange(a.shape[0])%(x+y)>=x]`

Comment: @soubaboy exactly :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid creating copies and allocating new memory, you could use a window_view of two elements:

```
win = np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(a, 2)

array([[0, 1],
       [1, 2],
       [2, 3],
       [3, 4],
       [4, 5],
       [5, 6],
       [6, 7],
       [7, 8],
       [8, 9]])
```

And then only take every 4th window view:

```
win[::4].ravel()

array([0, 1, 4, 5, 8, 9])
```

Or directly go with the more dangerous `as_strided`, but heed the warnings in the [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view.html#numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view):

```
np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(a, shape=(3,2), strides=(32,8))
```

Comment: Oh I never heard about those submodules. I was considering something similar by reshaping and keeping only every other row but using a modulo feels a bit clearer